# For-Loop with Unrelated Conditions

Tags: c, for-loop

I am having difficulty understanding the following for-loop with multiple unrelated conditions:

```
double init, P[500],ta[500][500];
int a, i, N;
N=100;
P[0]=1;
for(init = 1., i = 0; i < N+1; P[i+1] = P[i] * 100, i++)
    for(a=0;a<N+1;a++)
       ta[i][a]=1.;
```

I understand in a normal situation it shall be the counter `i` that is initialized to `0`
and will be incremented till the condition `i<N+1` but what about `init=1`, `P[i+1]=P[i]*100` and how do they fit in?

Comment: How could we possibly tell if you don't show the body of the loop?

Comment: Is this question related to understanding code golf pehaps?

Comment: There is only one condition there... The stuff on either side of the semicolons are the initialisation and increment statements. The condition is in between and checks only one variable. To understand why they are there, understand what they do and apply that to the rest of the loop. They're just other ways to declare and update variables (or in fact do any expression, which can include assignment or function calls etc etc)

Comment: Aside: `P[i+1] = P[i] * 100` is not good code as `P[i]` is uninitialized.  Better to post compilable code.

Comment: Try a search on google.com with keywords `c programming comma operator`; some results lead back to SO

Comment: @underscore_d I think I do begin to understand what your are saying but they are not there in the rest of the loop.

Comment: one of the most prominent examples of: ***`How to do not program in C`***

Comment: @gfdsal Better with the update.  What is `N`? How is `i` declared?  Knowing these helps ID potential issues here.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i reupdated. If it is sufficient, please do care to reopen. I am coming from python to c, so still coping.

Comment: @Shark no, its not.

Comment: @gfdsal voted to re-open.  Tip: posting compilable code makes for better questions and allows for more use of automated tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every for loop has an initialization section, a condition section and a change of value section. They need not reuse the same variables. They can all be unrelated. So `init = 1., i = 0;` is the initialization section. In the condition section here `i < N+1;` all the loop cares for is a boolean value, which it gets. It does not matter where that value comes from. For the change of value mostly used for incrementing / decrementing values `P[i+1] = P[i] * 100, i++`. This is what is done. For all it matters you can leave that section blank and the program will still work. You can do the change inside the loop. All a for loop gives you is an elegant way to write an iteration. Doesn't mean that it is the only way to use it.

Comment: so `P[i+1] = P[i] * 100, i++` it is simultaneous gonna increment as well as update the array with incremented values?

Answer (score 1):

Expressions like `init = 1., i = 0` are called [comma expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other). Each subexpression is evaluated separately, one after the other. So before entering the `for-`loop the first time, both `init=1` and `i=0` get executed. The for loop's condition is simply `i<N+1`, and - after each iteration - the comma expression `P[i+1] = P[i] * 100, i++` will be evaluated (i.e. `P[i+1] = P[i] * 100` and then `i++`. That's all.

Comment: ok i understand why `i=0` is there but `init = 1.` isnt really used in the loop. So the second part `P[i+1] = P[i] * 100, i++` as you are saying is the compact way to include inside the loop? So the expression `P[i+1] = P[i] * 100` could have been in the body of the loop between curly brackets?